# Problem on ratio wrt time distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem, ratio

This is a rough translation from a local language so please bear with it,

Say we have two people, police $p1$ and thief $p2$.

$p1$ takes $4$ $steps$ and $p2$ takes $5$ $steps$ in the *same amount of time*. Also the distance $p1$ covers in $6$ $steps$ is equal to the distance $p2$ covers in $8$ $steps$.

**What is the ratio of their velocities?**

What I tried:

Let $p1$ and $p2$ cover $d1$ and $d2$ distance in 4 and 5 steps, also let say it takes $t1$ time for $p1$ to take 6 steps and $t2$ time for $p2$ to take 8 steps,
so $d1/d2 = 4/5$ and $t1/t2 = 6/8$, so I get $(d1/t1)/(d2/t2) = 16/15$

In my friend circle we are getting another result $15/16$ (if required I will add the procedure).

I just can't wrap my head around the relation of steps with the other units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the distance covered by $p_1$ in $6$ steps or $p_2$ in $8$ steps be $L$.

Then after one time unit, $p_1$ has travelled $\frac{4L}{6}$, and $p_2$ has travelled $\frac{5L}{8}$.

Velocity = Distance / Time, so the *ratio* of velocities is:

$$
\frac{p_1}{p_2}
=\frac{\frac{4L}{6}}{\frac{5L}{8}}
=\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{5}{8}}
=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{8}{5}
=\frac{16}{15}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.  I think you and your friends will find this  way of looking at it convincing:

In $24$ times units, $p_1$ takes $24\cdot4=96$ steps, and so covers $96/6=16$ units of distance.  In the same time, $p_2$ takes $24\cdot5=120$ steps, and covers $120/8=15$ units of distance.

Answer (score 1):

Although your answer is correct, your method looks wrong, I believe, because $\frac{d_1}{d_2}\neq \frac45$. $p_1$ takes $\frac86\times$ longer steps than $p_2$, so the distance covered by $p_2$ in time $t$ is $5D$, where $D$ is the length of a step $p_2$ takes, and that covered by $p_1$ in same time is $\frac86\times4D$. So, $\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{d_1/t}{d_2/t}=\frac{4\times\frac86}{5}=\frac{d_1}{d_2}=\frac{16}{15}$.

Comment: well I don't have a solid math background, but how does distance, let say for p2 equals 5t, I mean 5 is the number of steps and t is time so how does the units add up ?

Comment: @Julkar9 You can normalize the steps $p_2$ takes by $1$m. So, that $p_2$ travels $5$m in taking $5$ steps. This is possible because no matter what normalization we choose for a step, it cancels while taking the ratio.

Comment: @Julkar9 I edited the answer according to your doubt. Hope it helps!

Comment: First ,thanks for your help, and sorry if these questions are trivial, but the distance covered by p2 in time t, why is it 5Dt ? let say D is m and t is sec. Doesn't the unit becomes m*sec ?

Comment: @Julkar9 My bad! I accidentally inserted a "$t$" there. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let the police have run step length  l1 and the thief l2;

Let the police have run speed  v1  thief v2;

we have
$$\dfrac{4\; l1}{v1}= \dfrac{5\; l2}{v2} \tag1$$
and
$$ 6 \;l1 = 8\; l2 \tag2$$
Divide and simplify
$$\dfrac{v1}{v2}= \dfrac{16}{15} >1 \tag3$$
So the police can catch the thief.